# Which Exchange Correlational Functional should be chosen for calculation of optical properties in VASP using LOPTICS tag?

Tags: vasp, optical-properties, correlation-functions

I am planning on calculating optical properties mainly dielectric constant using LOPTICS tag in VASP. Now for my electronic calculations I have been using HSE06 mainly because of higher accuracy of electronic propetrties with hybrid functionals. For my Structural calculations GGA is good enough. But as I am required to use `ALGO=Exact` and doubling/tripling the required number of bands(recommended on VASP web page [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Dielectric_properties_of_SiC) and [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/LOPTICS)) I don't wanna unnecessarily use a computationally demanding functional like HSE06.

Is PBE good enough for calculation of optical properties? There is a lot of literature on underestimation of band gap in DFT but very little about optical properties.

Comment: This question is of interest to me as well. I found this article (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2590147822000493) somewhat helpful, though it probably doesn't constitute a complete answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks this does give a small comparative analysis. However I have not been able to find an extensive study for comparison of this. But according to my observation comparing PBE and HSE06, there is some higher accuracy when using hybrid functionals but the difference is not that much.

Comment: For the frequency-dependent dielectric function, I have seen examples where GW-BSE agrees the best with experimental spectra. But for the static dielectric constants, I wonder if using PBE would be sufficient. This paper (https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.115151) has some benchmarking.

Comment: @CWTan do you think you can expand those comments into an answer? Chan, are you still actively seeking answers? Or have you figured it out now? Please update us!

Comment: @NikeDattani Unfortunately, I don't think my previous comments are enough to directly answer the question, seems like a proper benchmarking study for the frequency-dependent dielectric function is required.

Comment: @CWTan thanks for helping Chan in the comments anyway!